# How to add a white space around an image using online tools like Pixlr Editor or imagemagick ?

Tags: image-processing, whitespace

I want to put some white space around an image in equal length. I want to maintain the image pixel ratio to 12:7 too. Any help would do a great help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another method using Imagemagick V7:

```
magick ShF4m.jpg -background white -gravity center -extent "%[fx:w+20]"x"%[fx:h+20]" result.jpg
```

Open image, set the background to white, set the gravity to the centre so the -extent extends the canvas in all directions, increase the canvas size by 20px on the width and 20px on the height.

Comment: bonzo's method will add the border outside the image.  That is equivalent to convert image -bordercolor white -border 20 result. Unfortunately, neither approach will not preserve aspect ratio

Comment: hmmm ri8 @fmw42

Comment: Let me clarify. My original approach adds the border inside the image and so will preserve the aspect. Bonzo's approach and my commented equivalent will not preserve the aspect ratio, since they add the border outside the image.

Comment: fmw42 is correct about using the -border option I was not thinking! The image will get bigger by 20px in each axis but the aspect ratio will stay the same: "Aspect ratio is the ratio of the width to the height of an image or screen". You could reduce the size the original image using -resize by 20px on each axis and then add the 10px border if you want to keep the aspect ratio and size also keeping all the picture. This statement is confusing "in equal length".

Answer (score 3):

It would be simple in ImageMagick if you wrote over the inside of the border with white. That way you do not change the image dimensions nor aspect ratio.  Here I shave 10 pixels all around and then put a 10 pixel white border all around.  Here I will add a red border just to make it visible. But you can change red to white later.

[image]

```
convert barn.jpg -shave 10x10 -bordercolor red -border 10x10 barn_border10.jpg
```

[image]

It would be very hard to add white outside the image of equal amount and keep the aspect ratio. I do not think you can have equal white border amounts and keep the aspect ratio.